# Import object attributes as global variables

Tags: python

I have a small python script which serves as a configuration file. The structure is like

```
project=Project(param1=..., param2=..., ...)
project.add_plugins(P1(data=project.db1()),
                    P2(data=project.db2()))
project.run_plugins(get_selected())
```

For easier notation I'd like to introduce something like

```
db1=project.db1
db2=project.db2
```

for all attributes of project, so that I don't need to write out `project.`. Can you suggest a nice way of doing that for all attributes automatically?

Comment: I suggest not doing that (even if it is possible), since it's likely to get messy. Rather, you should rename `project` to something shorter, like `proj` or `P`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea (see my comment to your question), but you can do it with the [globals](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals) built-in:

```
for attr in dir(project):
    if not attr.startswith("_"):
        globals()[attr] = getattr(project, attr)
```

The reason I don't think it's a good idea is that it pollutes the global namespace with something that was to begin with very neatly wrapped in a logically named namespace. Your going from better to worse.

The Zen of Python (`import this`) has a last line which reads:

```
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! However the comment isn't exactly constructive since you question the question without knowing all the background. It's some sort of configuration script for intermediate user and not a full program. So it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from writing:

```
db1=project.db1
db2=project.db2
```

It looks from your example that db1 and db2 are methods. If so you can do the assignment and call `db1()` or `db2()` as you wish.

If they are mutable attributes you can mutate them safely but be aware that rebinding the short names wouldn't affect the original attributes in any way (just as rebinding a name created from an import won't affect the original).

Python's standard library uses this trick in a few places. For example look at `random.py` which exposes the `Random` class but also creates an instance of it and exports the methods of that instance through plain names:

```
# Create one instance, seeded from current time, and export its methods
# as module-level functions.  The functions share state across all uses
#(both in the user's code and in the Python libraries), but that's fine
# for most programs and is easier for the casual user than making them
# instantiate their own Random() instance.

_inst = Random()
seed = _inst.seed
random = _inst.random
uniform = _inst.uniform
triangular = _inst.triangular
...
```

To do it automatically I would use a decorator to build the `__all__` list of exported names (which you would want for anyone importing your module) and then create the names separately after you've instantiated the class.

```
__all__ = []
def exported(f):
    __all__.append(f.__name__)
    return f
class Project:
    @exported
    def db1(self): ...
project = Project()

for name in __all__:
    if hasattr(project, name):
        globals()[name] = getattr(project, name)
```